# How was Jango Fett chosen?

Tags: star-wars, attack-of-the-clones

In *Star Wars Episode II: Attack of the Clones* we are introduced to Jango Fett, a feared bounty hunter who is not only hired to kill Padme Amidala but is also the template for the Clone Army troopers, but how was he chosen? Jango himself says he was "recruited by a man called Tyranus" but doesn't say why or how.

It is mentioned in a *Legends: Republic* comic that he was chosen by a competition but is there any canon (pre-Disney or Disney, and non-Legends) version of the selection process?

[image: A character explains to a clone trooper how Dooku told him that Fett was the best warrior in the galaxy and won some bounty-hunter competition to become the basis for the clones]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

His reputation preceded him.

> [image: Fett meets with Tyranus who explains the job (hired to be the clones' template) and why he chose Fett: because of his reputation of skill and discretion in his line of work]
>
> <sub><sup>[*Age of Republic: Jango Fett #1*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Age_of_Republic_-_Jango_Fett_1)</sup></sub>

Comment: I may be incorrect but I believe the overall plot of the videogame *Star Wars: Bounty Hunter* was about how Jango ultimately got selected. In Legends, of course.

Comment: @SpaceWolf1701 - OP was, of course, asking about canon sources

Comment: So they did. I misread based on the "Pre-Disney" descriptor, since anything pre-Disney was by default "Legends".

Comment: @SpaceWolf - Even if it's not canon, it's probably worth posting as an answer to the question. As long as you point out that it's Legends, it's still worthy of upvotes.

Comment: @Valorum is that all the explanation given? I know you're high standards and wealth of archives, it just seems a little week to give such an important character such a poor intro.

Comment: @SeamustheDog - That's your lot from a canon perspective.

Comment: @Valorum that's a shame, could have saved doing the entire prequels by having someone say "Darth Vade was a pupil of mine, till he turned to evil".....